# mono systemd service wont start

Tags: ubuntu, mono, systemd

I have a an application I am trying to run with mono through systemd on ubuntu
When I run

```
systemctl status myservice.service
```

I get the following:

```
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

My service file is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=The description
After=network.target

[Service]
User=theuser

ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono -- /home/pathtoservice/myapplication.exe --parameter1=p1 --parameter2=p2 


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have ran:

```
/usr/bin/mono -- /home/pathtoservice/myapplication.exe --parameter1=p1 --parameter2=p2
```

from the command line and it works.
Any ideas on what is wrong?

I presume it is in service file but have looked at other examples and cant see what is wrong with it.
New to ubuntu so not sure where to look to diagnose the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check your logs:

```
journalctl -u myservice.service
```

Adding this to your unit file may improve the logging:

```
StandardOutput=journal+console
```

In some cases if some logging happens just before the service exits, the logs won't get tagged with the the service, so after you run the service, also look at:

```
journalctl
```

For entries just after your service exited.

Also, instead using the `network.target`, try the `network-online.target`.

I presume the app runs OK from the command line by itself. Assuming it works that way and not from systemd, differing environment variables can be an issue.  Add a line to the top of your app to dump all the environment variables and compare that output when run from `systemd` vs the CLI.

Finally, review the docs for [Type=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=). If the default Type= doesn't apply to your case, set this appropriately.

Future questions specific to `systemd` may be better answered at the [Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) as they don't directly relate to programming.

Comment: thanks mark looking at journalctl pointed that the user did not have permission to a directory. Not an issue running from the command line as I was running as root